# How to pass blank value as a parameter to a parameterized query and get all data?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with 5 columns and I want to define one parameterized select query to get some rows.

```
ID    Date      LetterNumber    divider1    divider2
-----------------------------------------------------
1   01/01/2013    2654            work       sent
2   01/01/2013    8796            vacation   sent
3   05/01/2013    4638            home       recived
4   05/01/2013    4695            work       recived
5   05/01/2013    2356            child      recived
6   09/03/2013    1358            child      recived
7   20/06/2013    1976            work       sent
8   21/06/2013    2468            vacation   sent
9   21/06/2013    9764            home       sent
10  30/08/2013    5346            work       recived
```

I want to write ONE query and pass parameters for each `divider1` , `divider2` and get some data. but some times I may not use one of parameters. for example some times I need to get data by filtering `divider2` and get just "sent" and some times filtering `divider1` and `divider2` to get `LetterNumber` having "work" value on `divider1` and "sent" value on `divider2`. 
So, is there a way to sent a blank value as a parameter to unfiltered the field dynamically ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your parameters for divider1 and divider2 are `@d1` and `@d2` you can get your data like:

```
select
    ID,
    Date,
    LetterNumber,
    divider1,
    divider2
from your_table
where 
    (divider1 = @d1 or @d1 is null)
    and (divider2 = @d2 or @d2 is null)
```

In this case, if you passing `null` to any of parameters - it will not be used in filtering.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ID, Date, LetterNumber, divider1, divider2
FROM TableA
WHERE (@divider1 = divider1 OR @divider1 IS NULL OR @divider1 = '') AND
(@divider2 = divider2 OR @divider2 IS NULL OR @divider2 = '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use OR  Condition for example

```
select * from yourTable where divider1=value1 OR divider2=value2
```